# Install Linux (Mint 16) on drive from temporary second drive

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint

I have an unused hard disk onto which I want to install Linux Mint.

I do not own a DVD-drive, but a working drive with a Linux Mint installation.

I would like to temporary boot this second drive, and install Linux Mint onto the actual drive from there.

Can this be accomplished without much magic?

Comment: You could make a live USB and then clone the drive to the other one, or just use put linux mint on a live USB and do a completely clean install to the pc.

Comment: You can install Linux Mint from USB-Stick [Click-here][1]


  [1]: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/